# How Can You Trigger Only the Deployment Steps in Bitbucket Pipelines?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

Is there a way to trigger only the deployment steps in a Bitbucket pipeline?

Currently my pipeline builds a series of Docker images, pushes it to a registry, and deploys the image to Kubernetes. My helm charts and values are checked into a different repo and if I want to deploy any changes, I will have to re-build all the Docker images in order to complete a deployment (or do it manually on the terminal). The build process is quite time consuming (anywhere between 5-20 minutes for different apps) so waiting for the build is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably just use a separate pipeline configured for `deploy` branch. For example:

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Build and test
        script:
          - python build-test.py
  deploy:
    - step:
        name: Deploy to staging
        deployment: staging
        script:
          - python deploy.py
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't think there is a real solution to my question but just want some clarification on what you are suggesting. So you would trigger the deploy branch manually? Wouldn't this be better as a custom pipeline step? My thoughts was to have a build and deploy pipeline for default and possibly a custom step to just deploy the code but would prefer to not have duplicate code in the pipeline which isn't a big deal as the pipeline just calls a script which uses env vars.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really write it down in full detail, because of client confidentiality. But at a client of mine we had a similar issue and split our process into two steps.

First, we build our app and run all the tests. If that succeeds, we "publish" the artifact to S3.

This then triggers our next step: deployment. This pipeline will pull in the artifact from S3 and deploy it to an environment.

When we want to deploy to the next environment, there's no need to build the entire app again. We just take the artifact from S3 and deploy it to another environment. This ensures the artifact doesn't change between environments. The only difference is environment variables.

We implemented this by creating custom publish and deploy scripts. You could also publish the artifact to BitBucket, but they are removed after some time. In S3, it's under our control.

I hope this points you in a helpful direction.